# markable --> ...was markably exhausting to her?

Tags: word-usage

Officially, the adverb 'markably' derived from 'markable' appears not to exist. At least all classical dictionaries (OED, OALD, CALD, LALD, etc. even WordNet v3.1) have no entry.

Theoretically, deriving 'markably' would be allowed. Hence, I want to know on a scale from 0 (not awkward at all) to 10 (super awkward) how awkward it sounds to use '...has been markably exhausting to her'

Which alternative expressions would you suggest in case that you recommend against using 'markably exhausting'?

Thank you for any valuable input.

Comment: Are you sure about the word "markable"? It only appears in the Oxford Dictionary and it's labeled as rare. Have you checked if remarkable/remarkably are suitable for your context?

Comment: Are you thinking of *mark**ed**ly*?  *Markable* means *capable of being marked* (like, marked with a pen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the vast majority of people would consider 'markably' a mistake for 'markedly'. It's one of those words that arises from mishearing of similar consonant sounds.

Other examples are 'nucular' (popular with President George W Bush) and 'trader' (when used by North Americans in the context of 'traitor').

Having said that, it may be a word that is becoming so commonly used that it stops being a mistake and starts being considered an acceptable alternative. I believe some dictionaries already mention it as an alternative. It makes a certain amount of logical sense, especially when you consider words like 'remarkably' which have a related meaning.

And to answer your question directly, I would say

> It was remarkably exhausting

By contrast

> It was markedly exhausting

is technically fine, but in casual conversation it is likely to sound almost archaic and overly formal.